# Will I have to reset my Nexus 7?

Tags: browser, nexus-7, chrome-for-android

I have a Nexus 7 running Jelly Bean. I was downloading a file and somehow I managed to remove a tick mark some were. Now I can not download anything from the net without Chrome stops working. Then I tried to download a backup program from Play Store, that mad Play store stop.

How and where do I add the tickmark again? Will I have to reset my Nexus 7? If so are all the app I bought then lost?

Comment: No, bought apps are tied to your google account

Answer (score 0):

If youre talking about applications (.apk) downloaded from google chrome and not the play store then you need to go into Settings > Security > Unknown Sources

Comment: I am talking about Play store. During download I removed a tick mark and now I can not open play store

Comment: I did not find a solution, so I ended up reseting the nexus

Comment: You must've disabled **Background Data**

Answer (score 0):

**Q**: How and where do I add the tickmark again?
**A**: Who could possibly know what you need more than yourself?

**Q**: Will I have to reset my Nexus 7?
**A**: Follow below steps, you'll be fine.

**Q**: If so are all the app I bought then lost?
**A**: As Flow said, you can recover them from Google Play store later on. If you feel not safe, use [AppSaver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.IQBS.android.appSaver&hl=en) to back them up.

### Resetting your android phone

Before resetting your phone, you have to save your data (pics, music, movies, contacts...).

- If you have a google email account, saving your contacts is not
  needed, you can just sync it to the cloud.
- Concerning your apps, as Flow said, you can recover them from Google Play store later on.
- Backing up pics, movies and music is necessary. I recommend you to back up your entire data storage, it contains apps private files, office documents, few stuff that you could easily forget to back up otherwise...

When those steps are done, you can safely reset your phone, it will be like a second life for it :-).